# Problema al instalar ruby 2.4.6 en ubuntu

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby

Hola no tengo mucha experiencia con linux ni ruby pero por trabajo debo usarlos, mi problema es que me piden la version de ruby 2.4.6 y no hay caso en instalarlo, me da ese error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intente de ambas formas alguien con mas experiencia que me ayude

---

aun no me resulta, siguen saliendo estos errores con

```
    $ sudo apt-get update 
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade 
    $ rvm install 2.4.6 

    sudo apt-get update
        Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
        Obj:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                 
        Obj:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com eoan InRelease                                                                        
        Obj:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x eoan InRelease                                                                                  
        Obj:6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                       
        Obj:7 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                           
        Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                   
        Des:9 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97,5 kB]                               
        Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic'security InRelease                                            
        Des:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97,5 kB]                                    
        Obj:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/rvm/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                
        Des:13 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease [88,8 kB]                                            
        Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu eoan Release                                                            
          404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
        Err:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic'security Release
          404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.173 80]
        Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
        E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu eoan Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
        N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
        N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
        E: El repositorio «http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic'security Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
        N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
        N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios
```

```
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
    Creando árbol de dependencias       
    Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
    Calculando la actualización... Hecho
    Los siguientes paquetes se han retenido:
      ruby
    Se actualizarán los siguientes paquetes:
      grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpython3.7
      libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libsystemd0 libudev1 python3.7 python3.7-minimal systemd systemd-sysv udev
    18 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 1 no actualizados.
    Se necesita descargar 15,8 MB de archivos.
    Se utilizarán 58,4 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
    ¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
    Des:1 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 242-7ubuntu3.2 [1.202 kB]
    Des:2 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 242-7ubuntu3.2 [76,5 kB]
    Des:3 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 242-7ubuntu3.2 [9.368 B]
    Des:4 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 libnss-systemd amd64 242-7ubuntu3.2 [126 kB]
    Des:5 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 242-7ubuntu3.2 [130 kB]
    Des:6 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 systemd amd64 242-7ubuntu3.2 [3.439 kB]
    Des:7 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 242-7ubuntu3.2 [260 kB]
    Des:8 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 python3.7 amd64 3.7.5-2~19.10 [301 kB]
    Des:9 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 libpython3.7 amd64 3.7.5-2~19.10 [1.483 kB]
    Des:10 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 libpython3.7-stdlib amd64 3.7.5-2~19.10 [1.731 kB]
    Des:11 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 python3.7-minimal amd64 3.7.5-2~19.10 [1.766 kB]
    Des:12 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 libpython3.7-minimal amd64 3.7.5-2~19.10 [546 kB]
    Des:13 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 grub2-common amd64 2.04-1ubuntu12.1 [588 kB]
    Des:14 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 grub-pc amd64 2.04-1ubuntu12.1 [124 kB]
    Des:15 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 grub-pc-bin amd64 2.04-1ubuntu12.1 [969 kB]
    Des:16 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64-signed amd64 1.128.1+2.04-1ubuntu12.1 [467 kB]
    Des:17 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin amd64 2.04-1ubuntu12.1 [700 kB]
    Des:18 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 grub-common amd64 2.04-1ubuntu12.1 [1.859 kB]
    Descargados 15,8 MB en 4s (4.201 kB/s)  
    Preconfigurando paquetes ...
    (Leyendo la base de datos ... 229167 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../udev_242-7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando udev (242-7ubuntu3.2) sobre (242-7ubuntu3) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../libudev1_242-7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando libudev1:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.2) sobre (242-7ubuntu3) ...
    Configurando libudev1:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.2) ...
    (Leyendo la base de datos ... 229167 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../systemd-sysv_242-7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando systemd-sysv (242-7ubuntu3.2) sobre (242-7ubuntu3) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../libnss-systemd_242-7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando libnss-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.2) sobre (242-7ubuntu3) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../libpam-systemd_242-7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.2) sobre (242-7ubuntu3) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../systemd_242-7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando systemd (242-7ubuntu3.2) sobre (242-7ubuntu3) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../libsystemd0_242-7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando libsystemd0:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.2) sobre (242-7ubuntu3) ...
    Configurando libsystemd0:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.2) ...
    (Leyendo la base de datos ... 229167 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../00-python3.7_3.7.5-2~19.10_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando python3.7 (3.7.5-2~19.10) sobre (3.7.5~rc1-2) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../01-libpython3.7_3.7.5-2~19.10_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando libpython3.7:amd64 (3.7.5-2~19.10) sobre (3.7.5~rc1-2) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../02-libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.5-2~19.10_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.5-2~19.10) sobre (3.7.5~rc1-2) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../03-python3.7-minimal_3.7.5-2~19.10_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando python3.7-minimal (3.7.5-2~19.10) sobre (3.7.5~rc1-2) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../04-libpython3.7-minimal_3.7.5-2~19.10_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 (3.7.5-2~19.10) sobre (3.7.5~rc1-2) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../05-grub2-common_2.04-1ubuntu12.1_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando grub2-common (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) sobre (2.04-1ubuntu12) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../06-grub-pc_2.04-1ubuntu12.1_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) sobre (2.04-1ubuntu12) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../07-grub-pc-bin_2.04-1ubuntu12.1_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando grub-pc-bin (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) sobre (2.04-1ubuntu12) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../08-grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.128.1+2.04-1ubuntu12.1_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.128.1+2.04-1ubuntu12.1) sobre (1.128+2.04-1ubuntu12) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../09-grub-efi-amd64-bin_2.04-1ubuntu12.1_amd64.deb ...
    Desempaquetando grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) sobre (2.04-1ubuntu12) ...
    Preparando para desempaquetar .../10-grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu12.1_amd64.deb        
    ...
    Desempaquetando grub-common (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) sobre (2.04-1ubuntu12) ...
    Configurando systemd (242-7ubuntu3.2) ...
    Instalando una nueva versión del fichero de configuración /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolved ...
    [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/elasticsearch.conf:1] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/elasticsearch → /run/elasticsearch; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:1] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:3] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:4] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:5] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/log → /run/speech-dispatcher/log; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    Configurando libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 (3.7.5-2~19.10) ...
    Configurando grub-common (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) ...
    update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
    Configurando udev (242-7ubuntu3.2) ...
    update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
    Configurando python3.7-minimal (3.7.5-2~19.10) ...
    Configurando grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) ...
    Configurando systemd-sysv (242-7ubuntu3.2) ...
    Configurando libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.5-2~19.10) ...
    Configurando libpython3.7:amd64 (3.7.5-2~19.10) ...
    Configurando grub2-common (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) ...
    Configurando libnss-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.2) ...
    Configurando grub-pc-bin (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) ...
    Configurando grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu12.1) ...
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-23-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-23-generic
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-22-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-22-generic
    Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    Found Ubuntu 19.10 (19.10) on /dev/sdb3
    Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
    done
    Configurando libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.2) ...
    Configurando python3.7 (3.7.5-2~19.10) ...
    Configurando grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.128.1+2.04-1ubuntu12.1) ...
    Instalando para plataforma x86_64-efi.
    Instalación terminada. No se notificó ningún error.
    Procesando disparadores para libc-bin (2.30-0ubuntu2) ...
    Procesando disparadores para man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
    Procesando disparadores para dbus (1.12.14-1ubuntu2) ...
    Procesando disparadores para install-info (6.6.0.dfsg.1-2ubuntu2) ...
    Procesando disparadores para desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.133ubuntu10) ...
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-23-generic
```

Comment: en la primera pantalla te aparece que tus repos están desactualizados.
Puedes hacer un:
sudo apt-get update y luego, un sudo apt-get upgrade. Para luego ejecutar el comando rvm install 2.4.6

Comment: Como sugerencia, siempre puedes añadir los mensajes de error como texto, que es preferible para que todos puedan verlos y revisarlos fácilmente.

Comment: aun sale el error, abajo lo deje como texto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la linea de comandos ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

y te va a mostrar error en alguna librería/repositorio

muevete a la carpeta:

```
$ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

y elimina el repositorio que te da error

vuelve a ejecutar

```
$ rvm install ...version
```

y ya estaría resuelto

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué versión de ubuntu tienes? Te lo digo porque creo que hace tiempo los repositorios de las versiones 1.7 hacia abajo dejaron de funcionar pero no estoy seguro del todo. A parte, prueba con el siguiente comando `$sudo apt-get install ruby` solo para ver que error te sale.